# Showing that $\int_{X}\log(f)d\mu\le \mu(X)\log{1\over \mu (X)}$ without using Jensen's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Showing that $\int_{X}\log(f)d\mu\le \mu(X)\log{1\over \mu (X)}$ given that $\int_{X}fd\mu=1$ for positive $f$ without using Jensen's inequality.

We weren't presented with Jensen's inequality, but with Fubini's Theorem and another theorem which is:

> in a finite measure space $(X,\mu,\Sigma)$
> $f\in L_{0}^{+}(\Sigma)$ satisfies $\int_{X}{fd\mu}=\int_{(0,\infty)}\mu(\{f>t\}dm(t))$

At first I thought I should use $\{|f|<{1\over \mu(X)}\}$,$\{|f|\ge{1\over \mu(X)}\}$ and show that  if $\int \log f d\mu> \mu(X)\log({1\over \mu(X)})$, then

$\int \log{f}d\mu\le \mu(\{|f|<{1\over \mu(X)}\})\log{1\over \mu(X)}+\int_{\{|f|\ge {1\over \mu(X)}\}}\log{f} d\mu$ and therefore

$\log{1\over \mu(X)}(\mu(X)-\mu(\{|f|<{1\over \mu(X)}\}))=\log{{1\over \mu(X)}}(\mu(\{|f|\ge {1\over \mu(X)}\}))<\int_{\mu(\{|f|\ge\})}\log{f} d\mu$

which I can't seem to contradict. Any ideas how this can be shown, without using Jensen's Inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that $$\log(x) \leq \log(s) - 1 + \frac xs$$ for any constant $s >0$. Then take $s= \mu(X)^{-1}$ and use this bound to get an upperbound for the integrand and hence also for the integral. (This is, all said and done, just Jensen’s inequality.)

Comment: Thank you for answering!
Can I take $x$ to actually be $f$?

Comment: Yes that’s the idea.